# iOS SamplerUnit stuck notes

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiokit, coremidi

I'm developing an AUSampler based application for iOS12.4x (I'm on High Sierra so can't develop for iOS13+, I'm using Xcode 10.3).

It manages incoming MIDI messages through the MIDIReadProc handler.

I noticed stuck notes (as if some note off messages werent't handled) when playing many note repeatedly at the same time.
I called MusicDeviceMIDIEvent directly from MIDIReadProc handler, however it didn't fix the problem.

UPDATE : using new AVAudioUnitSampler (and AVAudioEngine/AVAudioSession instead AUGraph) didn't helped.

UPDATE :
Using AudioKit 4.8 and wrapper classes (AKMidiSampler/AKAppleSampler) for Apple's AVAudioUnitSampler fixed the problem, so the problem may come from the way I manage midi messages (however it is similar as how AudioKit does).

New code I'm using (older code with MIDIReadProc was Objective-C) :

> err = MIDIInputPortCreateWithBlock(client, portName, &port,
> onMIDIMessageReceived)

And handler defined as :

> ```
> func onMIDIMessageReceived(message: UnsafePointer<MIDIPacketList>,
> srcConnRefCon: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
>
>     let packetList: MIDIPacketList = message.pointee
>     let n = packetList.numPackets
>     var packet = packetList.packet
>     for _ in 0 ..< n {
>       
>         let mes: UInt8 = packet.data.0 & 0xF0
>         let ch: UInt8 = packet.data.0 & 0x0F
>         if mes == 0x90 && packet.data.2 != 0 {
>            
>             let noteNo = packet.data.1
>             let velocity = packet.data.2
>             DispatchQueue.main.async {
>                 self.delegate?.noteOn(ch: ch, note: noteNo, vel: velocity)
>             }
>         } else if (mes == 0x80 || mes == 0x90) {
>             
>             let noteNo = packet.data.1
>             let velocity = packet.data.2
>             DispatchQueue.main.async {
>                 self.delegate?.noteOff(ch: ch, note: noteNo, vel: velocity)
>             }
>         }
>         let packetPtr = MIDIPacketNext(&packet)
>         packet = packetPtr.pointee
>     }
> }
> ```

I also tested without DispatchQueue.main.async (using it instead in the delegate when calling the sampler methods), same problem.

I would like not having to rely on Audiokit as I think this is overhead for what I plan (I want to learn/control all of my code).

Comment: Have you checked to see if some packets have additional bytes?  My first thought is that by not looking at the length of the data in a packet, some data is being ignored. 

I’m not sure how CoreMidi defines a packet, but perhaps a single packet could have a single note on/off status byte followed by data for multiple notes? (MIDI has a concept of “running status” that allows repetitive status bytes to be omitted)  Or maybe you’ll need to handle additional status bytes in the data too?

Comment: Hi, you are right, after looking into audioKit source code and finding articles about managing MIDIPacket indeed they contain a tuple data. We have to check its total size and then iterating over the pointer to get messages (status byte followed by one or two value bytes). It now works, thanks